# PHP - Document_Root vs Sub-Domains

Tags: php, document-root

I have the following code in my configuration file to establish the root path which is then used throughout the application:

```
define('ROOT_PATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/MyAppFolder/');
```

The problem is that it does not seem to work with sub domains. if I try to include my configuration file into a PHP file that is on the sub domain, naturally, I get an error.

How can I get around this problem? How can I establish a root path that allows sub domains? I've never done this before so I haven't a clue how to go about it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something in your bootstrap file:

```
define( 'ROOT_PATH', dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) );
```

This obviously depends on if the first file to run is in a subdirectory or not.

e.g.

```
/docroot
- index.php --> define( 'ROOT_PATH', dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) );

/docroot
- /common
- - index.php --> define( 'ROOT_PATH', dirname( dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) ) );
```

A side note, this is really meant as a way to correctly access your applications files and not necessarily determine if you are in the document root of your web server. Anyway hope this helps, or at least gives you some ideas.