# MYSQL PHP direction error

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, direction

```
[31-Oct-2014 12:47:24 UTC] PHP Warning:  include_once(../connect/con.php) [<a href='function.include-once'>function.include-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/denzw681/public_html/u/userPages/check_login_status.php on line 3
[31-Oct-2014 12:47:24 UTC] PHP Warning:  include_once() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening '../connect/con.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/php') in /home/denzw681/public_html/u/userPages/check_login_status.php on line 3
[31-Oct-2014 12:47:24 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: con in /home/denzw681/public_html/u/userPages/check_login_status.php on line 26
[31-Oct-2014 12:47:24 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/denzw681/public_html/u/userPages/check_login_status.php on line 15
[31-Oct-2014 12:47:24 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /home/denzw681/public_html/u/userPages/check_login_status.php on line 16
```

I have folders this way:

**>> public_html/u/connect/con.php**

**>> public_html/u/userPages/check_login_status.php**

**>> public_html/u/userPages/php_parsers/photo_system.php**

Not sure how to sulve this issue (

**I can add the files code if needed to answer this question.**

P.S. website is **http://www.U.example.com/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the root of your site, with:

```
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/u/connect/con.php");
```

Or you can use the magic constant:

```
define( 'ROOT_PATH', dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) );
```

- Source: [PHP - Document_Root vs Sub-Domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710857/php-document-root-vs-sub-domains)

Comment: Then Rakesh's answer is pretty better. I've improved it a little using the magic __FILE__

Comment: Cool... that's helps...) the top answer)

Comment: Can't give you +1 only 13 reputation))

Answer (score 0):

you to give correct path of connection Try

```
include_once('../../connect/con.php');
```

or would be better if define your site url in common file like header.php

```
define('SITEURL', 'http://example.com/u/');
```

and use this to include files

```
include_once(SITEURL.'connect/con.php');
```

Comment: website doesn't work at all... not just specific page